# как правильно добавить технологию primefaces

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, primefaces

хочу реализовать возможности primefaces в моем проекте но скорее всего добавление jar файла primefaces в библиотеку проекта не помогает,подскажите что делать пожалуйста.Потому что в файле xhtml datatable все строчки горят желтыми и пишет "unknown tag(p:dataTable или p:column)"
в pom.xml нет зависимостей и репозиторий primefaces.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во-первых, советую пользоваться *сборщиком пакетов* - Maven  или Gradle. Тогда не надо будет заморачиваться с отдельными jar-файлами и зависимостями между ними.

Во-вторых, добавляешь в pom-файл зависимостей (для Maven) следующее:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

В-третьих, в XHTML-страницу надо добавить ссылку на пространство имен Primefaces (это позволит использовать тэги Primefaces):

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Так же некоторые IDE (например, InelliJ IDEA) используют подключение *Framework Support* (в данном случае - для Primefaces), что упрощает разработку.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ссылку на namespace primefaces в ваши xhtml файлы.

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```